# How can .where accept an array without braces?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm not sure how is this implemented, when you do something like:

```
Model.where(["subjects = ?", 1])
```

Rails allows you to omit the braces:

```
Model.where("subjects = ?", 1)
```

I know this is possible with hashes, but how is it possible so you can pass ANY number of arguments (you can have 100 question marks if you want) and for Rails to still interpret this as an array?

Comment: Do you want write where condition with mutliple subject ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby a method can accept [splat arguments](https://endofline.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/the-strange-ruby-splat/).

```
def foo(*a)
  a
end

foo('bar', 'baz')
# => ["bar", "baz"]
```

The splat gathers up any remaining arguments. You can even use it with regular arguments:

```
def foo(a, *b)
  b
end

foo('bar', 'baz')
# => ["baz"]
```

You can even do something like:

```
def foo(*a)
  a.length == 1 && a.first.is_a?(Array) ? a.first : a
end
```

Now calling `foo('bar', 'baz')` and `foo(['bar', 'baz'])` have the same return value.

However if what you want is a `WHERE` condition where the value can be one of many possible values you would write it like so:

```
Model.where(foo: [1, 2, 3, 5])
```

Which would create a `WHERE models.foo IN (1,2,3,5)` clause.

Comment: The more complex answer is that rails does not really treat `Model.where("subjects = ?", 1)` as an array. Rather it is a method with a complex signature that allows you to pass many different kinds of arguments. Its somewhat like `where(str_or_array = nil, *args, hash = {})`

Answer (score 0):

From the [Docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where)

```
Model.where(array)
```

If an array is passed, then the first element of the array is treated as a template, and the remaining elements are inserted into the template to generate the condition. Active Record takes care of building the query to avoid injection attacks, and will convert from the ruby type to the database type where needed. Elements are inserted into the string in the order in which they appear.

```
User.where(["name = ? and email = ?", "Joe", "joe@example.com"])
# SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = 'Joe' AND email = 'joe@example.com';
```